# What does it mean by saying that $u^n, J^n$ "$C^{\infty}$ converges" to u, J?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

The question arose while reading the big book of McDuff & Salamon. Here $\Sigma$ is Riemann surface and M is compact symplectic manifold. Let $u^n(n\in \mathbb N), u : \Sigma \rightarrow M$ be J-holomorphic curve and $J^n(n\in \mathbb N), J$ be almost complex structure on M.

A) What does it mean by saying that $u^n, J^n$ "$C^{\infty}$ converges" to u, J(respectively)?

B) And what does it mean by saying that $u^n$ converges to $u$ "uniformly with all derivative(on compact subset)?"

for A), I would appreciate for explaining other equivalent definition if there exists more than one. for B), I can imagine interpreting first derivative of $u$ as a operator norm $||du||$(given metric on M), but for higher derivative I don't know how to deal with it. does this need connection on the manifold? Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

(A) and (B) mean the same thing. Specifically, $u^n \to u$ in $C^\infty$ means the exact same thing as $u^n \to u$ uniformly with all derivatives on compact subsets.

(A) means that in on each compact subset $K$, for each $k \ge 0,$ $$\sup_K || D^k ( u^n - u) || \to 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty.$$
Similarly, replacing $u$ with $J$.

In order to define this norm, in principle you need some extra data, such as a metric and a connection on $M$ and on $\Sigma$. The point is that the induced norms are all equivalent (i.e. exists a $C > 0$ so $\frac{1}{C} || \cdot ||_1 \le || \cdot ||_0 \le C || \cdot ||_1$), so the convergence doesn't depend on the choices.

(This matters also when defining $W^{k,p}$ sections of a vector bundle, which also shows up in this book. The specific norm depends on some choices, but the topology induced on sections does not, since the norms are all equivalent.)